# Power Automate Desktop Fill Data from excel to website but multi UI ELEMENT

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I am a newbie working on power automate desktop and sorry if my english is not good. Currently I am making a flow that will populate the website from my excel. Excel I will have a list of lists I want it to populate in order. But I am having a problem that when I finish filling in the first position, it will show the second position and go on to third , ..... The HTML Input ID also changes in ascending order. So when I do this Flow, it only executes at the top of all my list from excel. Is there a way that can automatically jump the column according to that line UI element. Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhgxI.png)

Input text will increase like adGroupInfo.1.adcontent and then you fill that one it will show your second and i want to fill data from my excel to that it will be adgroupInfo.2.adcontent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbuMr.png)

It same all DIV, SPAN ,But different Input ID
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEooU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X32x5.png)

Answer (score 0):

For this you will make use of a variable.

Dummy data:

[image]

Navigate to the element in the element list.
The click on the 3 dots menu to see the options.
Select ***Edit***

[image]
[image]

Then scroll down to the enabled selector, this will in most cases be the **id** of the element on the web page.
[image]

replace the value with the name of the variable that will hold the control id value

[image]

Then in your loop assign the value of the UI element to the variable you used as the identifier.
Line 7  (red 2)
[image]

This should then fill the boxes as required.
[image]

Comment: Sorry for late response. It's all i need. Thank you sir ! 
I will learn more and try my best with your tutorial :)

Have a nice day CobyC !